# How to store month and year only and set day to 1 by default for all dates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a date as `2010-12-24`.

I need to store the date as `2010-12-01` in database table. This should be applicable for all dates.

When inserting another date `2010-12-25`, it should also be stored as `2010-12-01`, and for `2017-01-29`, it be `2017-01-01`.

How can I set the day to default 1?

I hope this is clear. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just do it in the application layer with string functions

Comment: Find first date of the month

Comment: If I were you, I would do this in code, I like to separate responsibilities, the database is for storage! I having business logic in Code and Database is very hard to maintain!

Comment: I'm doing this in Controller class too.. thanks for the suggestion though.. :) and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much simpler way is to use PHP's built-in date functions :

```
// here's your date
$date='2017-01-12';
// and here we transform it as we want
$date_first = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date));
// check out the result :)
echo $date_first;
```

Comment: nice answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

it can be done in mysql just fine, though.

```
set @date = '2017-12-25';
select str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(@date),' ',MONTH(@date),' 1'), '%Y %m %d');
```

You don't need to use the @date variable, just replace @date with the date you are need to insert and use str_to_date to replace the day with 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it directly in `MySql` as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2010-12-25', INTERVAL DAY('2010-12-25')-1 DAY)
```

Explanation:

```
1. DAY('2010-12-25')-1 DAY // will return 24
2. DATE_SUB('2010-12-25', INTERVAL 24) // will return 25-24 = 01 i.e. 2010-12-01
```

This will work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, adjust to your requirement

```
$today = date("Y-m", strtotime("2017-12-25"));
  $dbDate =  date ("Y-m-d", strtotime($today."-1"));
  echo $dbDate;
```

Pass $dbDate to the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$date='2017-01-12';

$date=explode('-',$date);
$date[2]=str_replace($date[2],'01',$date[2]);
$date=implode('-',$date);
print_r($date);
```

And the output is :

```
2017-01-01
```

So it will always replace the day with `01`.
After you can execute the insert query for the new date as it is already modified in the php.

Comment: explode, implode + str_replace just for a simple use case like that. Ugly

Comment: Just answered the OP question according to what was asked. I mean my solution is pretty simple.

Comment: Just commenting your answer because your code isn't easy to understand in a rapid way. What if the date come in another format ? You got an output with `-` between all parts. Moreover if the asker use this function at a high level in his application that could have performance looses. The best answer is the simplest and sturdy one :)

Comment: No need to use strings function when you already have date() in place for this